# Is it possible to have more than one modal inside of a modal?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I am using Bootstrap 3. I have been setting up this dialog or modal prompt for users when accessing the data to select options. The way this needs to be built it will have one modal open up another, which then opens another based on what button you choose.

I am sure I am just missing some piece of code that will connect the third modal. If you check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxdeveloperkr/q5xge9b4/), click the 'start here' button and then 'Contributions FROM:' and then click on 'Specific Contributor'

This will show you that the modal on the third dialog does not initialize. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!-- Ask Anything Button trigger -->
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#askanythingModal"><i class="fa fa-map-signs"></i> Start Here</a> 

<!-- Ask Anything Modal START -->
<div class="modal fade" id="askanythingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="askanythingModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i style="font-size: 35px!important;" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></button>
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Ask Anything</h3>
                </div><br>
                <blockquote style="text-align: justify;" class="well">First, click below to see who money came <strong>FROM</strong> or who money went <strong>TO</strong>.
                 Second, build your exact question by clicking options, then press <strong>GO</strong> and we'll provide the answer.</blockquote>
                 <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contribfromModal">Contributions FROM</a> | <a class="btn btn-info btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contribtoModal">Contributions TO</a> 
                 <h4 class="well">Currently Looking at: Contribution Data</h4>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Contributions FROM > BUTTON MODAL -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="contribfromModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contribfromModal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i style="font-size: 35px!important;" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></button>
                              <div class="modal-header">
                              <h3 class="modal-title">Show contributions FROM:</h3>
                              </div><br>
                                <div style="padding: 15px;" class="row"> <!--  first row of icons -->
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find a specific contributor by name" id="speccontriModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="speccontribModal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Specific Contributor</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything"><i class="fa fa-university"></i> Parent Organization</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find contributors by selected economic sectors"><i class="fa fa-industry"></i> Industry(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div> <!-- end first row -->
                                <div style="padding: 15px;" class="row"> <!-- second row of icons -->
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find contributors by city, state and zipcode"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Location(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Select contributors that are either individuals or non-individuals"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Types of Contributors</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find contributions by record level information, such as amount or date"><i class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Types of Records</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div> <!-- end second row -->
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- end modal -->

                <!-- Specific Contributor > BUTTON MODAL -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="speccontriModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="speccontriModal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i style="font-size: 35px!important;" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></button>
                              <div class="modal-header">
                              <h3 class="modal-title">Show contributions TO:</h3>
                              </div><br>

                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- end modal -->



<!-- Contributions TO > BUTTON MODAL -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="contribtoModal" tabindex="-2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contribtoModal" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="modal-content">
                          <div class="modal-body">
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i style="font-size: 35px!important;" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></button>
                              <div class="modal-header">
                              <h3 class="modal-title">Show contributions TO:</h3>
                              </div><br>
                                <div style="padding: 5px;" class="row"> <!--  first row of icons -->
                                <h4>By type of receiving committee (Filer)</h4>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Search for candidates who share attributes, such as political party, incumbency status, district, winners, year and more"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> Candidate(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                  <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Search for lawmakers who share attributes, such as political party, represented district and/or legislative committee"><i class="fa fa-gavel"></i> Lawmaker(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find state ballot initiatives and referendums by name, subject, state or year"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> Ballot Measure(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div> <!-- end first row -->
                                <div style="padding: 5px;" class="row">
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Select records of official state party committees"><i class="fa fa-industry"></i> Political Party Committees(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Select records within one or more State(s) or Jurisdiction(s)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Filer</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="padding: 5px;" class="row"> <!-- second row of icons -->
                                <h4>By State/Year</h4>
                                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Find state ballot initiatives and referendums by name, subject, state or year"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Specific State(s)</a>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <a class="btn btn-info btn-ask-anything" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Select records within one or more election year(s)"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i> Specific Election Years</a>
                                  </div>
                                </div> <!-- end second row -->
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div> <!-- end modal -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 issues:

1. You have the same `id = 'speccontriModal'` for both parent and the modal popup.
2. You are missing attribute `data-target` on the parent.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/q5xge9b4/1/

Comment: Wow. I guess another set of eyes did wonders for me there, gets crazy once you start nesting these modals. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Took me a while to scroll down and figure out what was wrong ;)